# Why was the Separatist army so weak?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, warfare, trade-federation

Correct me if I am wrong (please provide evidence that if I am wrong, provide a battle that the Separatists win during the Clone Wars era) but it seems to me that they never win any battles against the Republic.

Comment: Because seeing them beat the good guys wouldn't make good TV?

Comment: Related: http://boards.theforce.net/threads/separatist-victories-in-the-clone-wars.50024006/

Comment: "Clones can think creatively. You will find that they are immensely superior to droids."

Comment: Is there any way I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It wasn't really.

The Confederacy of Independent Systems/Sepratists were know to have won the Battles of

- [Abregado](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Abregado)
- [the Ryndellia system](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ryndellia_system)
- [Felucia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_battle_of_Felucia)
- [Devaron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Devaron)
- [Patitite Pattuna](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Patitite_Pattuna)
- [Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Dathomir)
- [Florrum](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_on_Florrum)

They also successfully conducted attacks on [Obi-Wan Kenobi's fleet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_on_Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_fleet) and [Mahranee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_on_Mahranee),
   as well as [the destruction of the Felucia medical station](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_the_Felucia_medical_station), [the
   Bombing of Coruscant's central power distribution grid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bombing_of_the_Coruscant_power_generator) and [the
   Devaron Massacre](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Devaron_massacre).

You should note that *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* frequently focused on the Republic's greatest heroes, such as Anakin Skywalker, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Mace Windu and the like. It isn't hard to assume that less talented Jedi were losing battles that we just didn't see.

Additionally, Palpatine was  manipulating both sides of the war. It's likely he prevented the Separatists from being too successful, as that would make controlling the entire Galaxy later on more difficult.